# pass options to mongoose schema toJSON transform inline (in expressjs)?

Tags: express, mongoose

I have a mongoose (3.1) 'Thing' schema whose toJSON I can customize in the following manner...

```
Thing.options.toJSON = {};
Thing.options.toJSON.transform = function (doc, ret, options){
  // do something to ret, depending on options                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

As noted in the code comment, I would like to change the JSON representation given the value of options. I would like to pass these options in an expressjs action, maybe...

```
app.get(..., function (req ,res){
  Thing.find({}, function(err, things){
    var myOptions = {...} // something application stateful
    return response.send(things) // MAYBE ADD OPTIONS HERE?
  });
});
```

How do I modify expressjs to allow me to supply options?

Thanks,

G

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could pass options in the route handler by passing them to the schema options:

```
app.get(..., function (req ,res){
  Thing.find({}, function(err, things){
    Thing.schema.options.toJSON.myOptions = {...} // something application stateful

    return response.send(things) // MAYBE ADD OPTIONS HERE?
  });
});
```

this way, the options will be available in the transform function as a property of the options object:

```
Thing.options.toJSON.transform = function (doc, ret, options){
  console.log(options.myOptions); // prints the app specific data provided earlier                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the accepted answer (@VladStirbu's) is wrong because the options are being set at the schema level. It's changing the schema, so those options will be available in subsequent calls, even if you don't request so explicitly.

The options should be set *inline*, individually for that call:

**Regular call using express:**

```js
app.get(..., function (req ,res){
  Thing.find({}, function(err, things){
    return response.send(things);
  });
});
```

**Call using express, but passing inline options to toJSON():**

```js
app.get(..., function (req ,res){
  Thing.find({}, function(err, things){

    let toJSONOptions;  // may be undefined, it's fine
    if ( /* whatever condition you decide */ ) {
      // this keeps the schema's original options:
      toJSONOptions = Object.assign({ }, Thing.schema.options.toJSON);
      // request to use original transform function, if any:
      toJSONOptions.transform = true;
      // set your own options to be passed to toJSON():
      toJSONOptions._options = {...}; // whatever you need here
    }

    return response.send( things.map(e => e.toJSON(toJSONOptions)) );
  });
});
```

No problem if `toJSONOptions = undefined`, it would be like a regular call to `toJSON()`, which is what express does when stringifying.

If you're using `findOne()` or `findById()`, then just return:

```js
    return response.send( thing.toJSON(toJSONOptions) );
```

This is the Mongoose commit that made me think of this:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/commit/1161f79effc074944693b1799b87bb0223103220